# Is it possible to instantiate a class from a string variable in python?

Tags: python, reflection, code-generation

Let's say I have a string that holds a valid python class (not a class name). E.g.:

```
class_template = """
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print('My name is: ' + self.name)

    def add_whatever(a, b):
        return a + b
"""
```

Is it possible in python to implement a function (`string_to_class` in the example below) that receives this string and creates a python class out of it so I can instantiate the class later on?

```
class_template = """
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print('My name is: ' + self.name)

    def add_whatever(a, b):
        return a + b
"""

MyClass = string_to_class(class_template)
my_class_instance = MyClass('Ben')

print(MyClass.add_whatever(2, 3))
my_class_instance.print_name()
```

The output should be:

```
5
My name is: Ben
```

One possible solution might be to write out the string to a `MyClass.py` file and use `__import__()` to load it. Is there any other (in memory) solution?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I raise the x/y question: **why** do you want to do this?  You have a couple of characteristics that smell like there's an inelegant system design behind the problem.

Comment: You can look into the `eval` function family, but let's see whether there's a design flaw first.

Comment: You could use `exec` for this (this is actually what `namedtuple` does, or did at some point).

Comment: @Prune I don't want to do this. I'm simply interested in pythons capabilities. That's all. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A commenter mentioned `exec`; this is how you would put it together:

```
def string_to_class(python_text):
    local_vars = {}
    exec(python_text, {}, local_vars)
    # assume just a single new symbol was created (the class), and return it
    return list(local_vars.values())[0]

class_template = """
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print('My name is: ' + self.name)

    @staticmethod
    def add_whatever(a, b):
        return a + b
"""

MyClass = string_to_class(class_template)
my_class_instance = MyClass('Ben')

print(MyClass.add_whatever(2, 3))
my_class_instance.print_name()
```

But like some of the other commenters mentioned, it's not a commonly-applied technique, so be careful with it. You'll also run into problems pretty quickly as your use case gets more complicated:

```
some_string_that_defines_a_base_class = "case Base..."
some_string_that_defines_a_derived_class = "case Derived(Base):..."

Base = string_to_class(some_string_that_defines_a_base_class)
# this will crash because Base isn't defined in the scope that the string
# is being evaluated with
Derived = string_to_class(some_string_that_defines_a_derived_class)
```

You can fix it with a direct call to [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) (the `string_to_class` function is simply not powerful enough), but it quickly gets very tricky to use: I haven't even mentioned how `import`s would work yet. There are other techniques (function decorators, metaclasses) that might allow you to do what you want to do that involve less pain, but sometimes `exec` really is your only option.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.